# Microsoft Graph API Multi tenant App-only auth scheme

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API provides [App-only authentication scheme](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only), which works perfectly for the tenant that owns an application.

I have an Azure tenant and I created the application inside it following documentation guide. My application is now able to obtain an access token using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token` endpoint, which allows me to query the Graph API for the users inside my tenant.

However, I would like my application to be able to obtain access tokens for other tenants as well. I suppose the external tenant owner should somehow insert my application inside their Azure tenant, apply certain app-only scopes and provide me the tenant id in order to query the token endpoint.

Is multi-tenancy possible for app-only authentication scheme?
How does the tenant owner insert my application into their Azure tenant?

Answer (score 1):

**Multi-tenancy for app-only is possible**, however, in order to enable this you require two things:

1. You need to have a web UI for the tenant admin to sign in to and perform admin consent in order to, as you called it, *"insert my application into their Azure tenant."* Make sure you add the query string parameter &prompt=admin_consent.

More info on admin consent: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview/#understanding-user-and-admin-consent

Sample controller method that "signs up" the user for an app via admin consent:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/OnboardingController.cs#L33-L58

2. You will need to keep track of which tenants consented to your application so that you can enabled the code that runs the app-only flow for them. Unlike the delegated flow, you can't use the common endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common) but rather need to use the tenant specific endpoint for each instance or run of the app only flow.

Comment: Is there a sample code for what you just described above?